# Optional element in "reduce inputs" clause

Tags: jq

I am working on this [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66436501/16241) that I got from an earlier question.

Here is what I currently have:

```
function data {
cat <<EOF
Security:ClientId=123456
Security:ClientSecret=abcdefg
AppSettings:Environment=Dev
AnotherCustomSetting=SomethingElse
EOF
}

data | jq -nR '

def parse: capture("(?:(?<group>[^:=]*):)?(?<property>[^=]*)=(?<value>.*)");

reduce inputs as $line ({};
   ($line | parse) as $envVar
   | if .[$envVar.group] != null then .[$envVar.group][$envVar.property] = ($envVar.value) else .[$envVar.property] = ($envVar.value) end)
'
```

My end goal is to have a Json file like this:

```
{
  "Security": {
    "ClientId": "123456",
    "ClientSecret": "abcdefg"
  },
  "AppSettings": {
    "Environment": "Dev"
  },
  "AnotherCustomSetting": "SomethingElse"      
}
```

In my previous question I did not indicate that I would need properties at the root level (`AnotherCustomSetting` in this case).

To try to get root level properties working, I modified the RegEx to have an optional group, but the original answer's `reduce inputs` did not anticipate the `group` being null (and failed with a null error when it was).  So I attempted to put an `if` statement in the `reduce inputs` section.  Unfortunately it is failing with the following error:

> jq: error (at :4): Cannot index object with null

Is it possible to do an `if then else` in a `reduce inputs` section like I am attempting?  If so, how is it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
def parse: capture("(?<x>[^:=]*)(:(?<y>[^:=]*))?=(?<value>.*)");

reduce inputs as $line ({};
   ($line | parse) as $p
   | if $p.y then .[$p.x][$p.y] = $p.value
     else .[$p.x] = $p.value end )
```

Of course this could be further robustified...

Comment: Thank you again!  I really appreciate you taking the time to answer my questions.