# Prepend text to jq output

Tags: bash, shell, jq

I have the following script (from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66450397/16241))

```
data() {
cat <<EOF
Security:ClientId=123456
Security:ClientSecret=abcdefg
AppSettings:Environment=Dev
AnotherCustomSetting=SomethingElse
EOF
}

data | jq -nR '

def parse: capture("(?<x>[^:=]*)(:(?<y>[^:=]*))?=(?<value>.*)");

reduce inputs as $line ({};
   ($line | parse) as $p
   | if $p.y then .[$p.x][$p.y] = $p.value
     else .[$p.x] = $p.value end )
'
```

It works fantastically, and outputs this json:

```
{
  "Security": {
    "ClientId": "123456",
    "ClientSecret": "abcdefg"
  },
  "AppSettings": {
    "Environment": "Dev"
  },
  "AnotherCustomSetting": "SomethingElse"
}
```

I am struggling to prepend and postpend some text to this output.  I need to prepend

```
appConfig = JSON.parse(`
```

and postpend

```
`);
```

So the final output would look like:

```
appConfig = JSON.parse(`{
  "Security": {
    "ClientId": "123456",
    "ClientSecret": "abcdefg"
  },
  "AppSettings": {
    "Environment": "Dev"
  },
  "AnotherCustomSetting": "SomethingElse"
}`);
```

I tried to do this by adding the following to the script:

```
 | xargs printf 'appConfig = JSON.parse(`%s`);`
```

but it either printed nothing, or (with some fiddling) printed my prepend and postpend text on each line of json (instead of just adding to the front and end of the whole json).

**How can I prepend and postpend text to this output?**

Comment: You could simply use jq’s support for string interpolation. That way, everything can be done in jq. See the jq manual for details. It’s really very easy.

Comment: @peak - Thank you for the tip!  The syntax was very easy.  Unfortunately it changed the output.  It took out the new lines and escaped all the double quotes `\"`.  (The `printf` solution worked out so I am good.)

Comment: You would of course have to use the -r command-line option.  If you want the JSON to be formatted nicely, you could instead append this to the jq program: `| "appConfig = JSON.parse(`", ., "`);"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
printf 'appConfig = JSON.parse(`%s`);' "$(
data | jq -nR '

def parse: capture("(?<x>[^:=]*)(:(?<y>[^:=]*))?=(?<value>.*)");

reduce inputs as $line ({};
   ($line | parse) as $p
   | if $p.y then .[$p.x][$p.y] = $p.value
     else .[$p.x] = $p.value end )
')"
```

To store in var

```
printf -v var 'appConfig = JSON.parse(`%s`);' "$(
data | jq -nR '

def parse: capture("(?<x>[^:=]*)(:(?<y>[^:=]*))?=(?<value>.*)");

reduce inputs as $line ({};
   ($line | parse) as $p
   | if $p.y then .[$p.x][$p.y] = $p.value
     else .[$p.x] = $p.value end )
')"

$ echo "$var"
appConfig = JSON.parse(`{
  "Security": {
    "ClientId": "123456",
    "ClientSecret": "abcdefg"
  },
  "AppSettings": {
    "Environment": "Dev"
  },
  "AnotherCustomSetting": "SomethingElse"
}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can append a `sed` to your pipeline:

```
sed '1s@^@JSON.parse(`@; $s@$@`);@'
```

It's composed by two substitutions:

- `1s@^@...@`: prepend to the first line
- `$s@$@...@`: append to the last line

Answer (score 1):

One all-jq possibility would be as follows:

```
jq -nRrj '
  def parse: capture("(?<x>[^:=]*)(:(?<y>[^:=]*))?=(?<value>.*)");
  reduce inputs as $line ({};
    ($line | parse) as $p
    | if $p.y then .[$p.x][$p.y] = $p.value
      else .[$p.x] = $p.value end )
  | "appConfig = JSON.parse(`", ., "`);"
'
```

With the sample input, this produces:

```
appConfig = JSON.parse(`{
  "Security": {
    "ClientId": "123456",
    "ClientSecret": "abcdefg"
  },
  "AppSettings": {
    "Environment": "Dev"
  },
  "AnotherCustomSetting": "SomethingElse"
}`);
```